# Counting the number of vowels in a string using for loops in Python

Tags: python

Python Code:

```
sentence = input('Enter a string:')
vowel = 'A,a,E,e,I,i,O,o,U,u'
Count = 0
for vowel in sentence:
   Count += 1
print('There are {} vowels in the string: \'{}\''.format(Count,sentence))
```

I am trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter a string. The program then returns the number of vowels in the string. However, the code just returns the number of letters, without regard for just giving back vowels.

Comment: Does it have to be done using a loop?

Comment: Note that you've defined a string of vowels, but are redefining the variable `vowels` in the loop.

Comment: Furthermore, you do no checks before deciding to increment the counter. How will the code know to increment the counter only for loops?

Comment: What checks are you saying that I should do?

Comment: You can only do it with a for loop too

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46397134/4909087

Comment: What does the .lower part after the setence do?

Comment: It converts your string to lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to use a simple RegEx.
The RegEx to match a vowel is `[aeiou]` (or `[aeiouy]` if you want to match "y" too).

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all occurences of a vowel in a sentence, use the `re.IGNORECASE` flag to ignore case.

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = "my name is Jessica"
>>> len(re.findall(r'[aeiou]', sentence, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
6
```

The advantage of this solution is that you can extend it easily to add accentuated characters or other unicode character:

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = "Dès Noël où un zéphyr haï me vêt de glaçons würmiens je dîne d’exquis rôtis de bœuf au kir à l’aÿ d’âge mûr & cætera !"
>>> len(re.findall(r'[aeiouyàâèéêëiïîöôüûùæœÿ]', sentence, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
41
```

Answer (score 3):

You've defined a string of vowels, but are redefining the variable vowels in the loop.

I'd recommend defining a `set` of vowels, and then incrementing your counter based on an `if` check.

```
vowels = set('aeiou')  

counter = 0
for c in sentence.lower():
    if c in vowels:
        counter += 1
```

Here, the `if c in vowels` will return `True` if `c` is a vowel (that is, `c` belongs to the set of vowels stored in `vowels`).

---

You could improve this solution with a `collections.Counter` object:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(sentence.lower())
counter = sum(c[v] for v in set('aeiou'))
```

Alternatively, you could use a `list comprehension` and count its length.

Comment: What is the .lower part after the word sentence for

Comment: @SeanLi It simplifies your code by converting the input to lowercase, so you can search for only 'aeiou' instead of 'aeiou' _and_ 'AEIOU'...

Comment: Why are you walking all the elements in the `Counter` object, up to 26, when you could just look up the five vowels in the counter?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't checking anywhere if the letters in the sentence are vowels. The syntax `for x in y:` defines a loop over an iterable object (string, list etc.) where for each loop iteration, the variable `x` is set to the next element of that iterable.

Your line `for vowel in sentence:` is simply defining a loop, where `vowel` is assigned to each letter of the input sentence. Your previous declaration of `vowel = ...` has no effect here.

A decent 1-liner to achieve the desired outcome would be:

```
sentence = input('Enter a string:')
vowels = 'aeiou'
count = len([c for c in sentence.lower() if c in vowels])
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you don't verify if the letter is a vowel. When you put 'vowel in sentence' on the for loop you just overwrites what is in vowel and vowel becomes each letter on sentence for each loop iteration.

```
sentence = input('Enter a string:')
vowel = 'A,a,E,e,I,i,O,o,U,u'
Count = 0
for letter in sentence:
  if letter in vowel.split(','):
    Count += 1
print('There are {} vowels in the string: \'{}\''.format(Count,sentence))
```

Comment: With your algorithm you also count the commas…

Comment: True, Laurent, i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3:

```
sentence = input('Enter a string:')
vowels = 'A,a,E,e,I,i,O,o,U,u'
Count = 0
for each_char in sentence:
    if each_char in vowels:
        Count += 1 
print('There are {} vowels in the string: \'{}\''.format(Count,sentence))
```

Comment: The commas in the `vowels` string don't have any effect except to slow down your code.

Comment: Yeah I agree. But that is how it is specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code using Counter of collections

```
import collections
vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
count = 0

sentence = input('Enter a string:').lower()
counter = collections.Counter(sentence)
for word in counter:
    if word in vowel:
        count += counter[word]

print('There are {} vowels in the string: \'{}\''.format(count,sentence))
```

Comment: For me, this is a near miss.  My first problem is that you loop over every letter in the counter collection (up to 26) when you only need to loop over your five vowels  -- counter differs from a dictionary in that a "miss" returns zero so it's OK to lookup a vowel that might be missing.  Second, you print out a *bruised* version of the user's input at the end, not the original.  It makes sense to lowercase but keep the original for output -- lower case the sentence where you pass it to `Counter()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = input('Enter a string:')
Count = 0
for eachLetter in sentence:
    if eachLetter.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        Count += 1
print('There are {} vowels in the string: \'{}\''.format(Count,sentence))
```

Comment: You'd likely get better performance if you did `in sentence.lower():` and simply used `eachLetter` instead of `eachLetter.lower()`.  This would make one method call where you have one method call per letter.  You're going to end up lower casing them all anyway, why not do them all at once?

Answer (score 0):

We only need lowercase vowels in a list because we turn the sentence into lowercase only with .lower()

Then we loop through each vowel and count how many of each vowel is found in the sentence with .count(). Then we aggregate the total Count until we end up with the total number of vowels.

```
sentence = 'This is a sentence'
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
Count = 0
for vowel in vowels:
    Count = Count + sentence.lower().count(vowel)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Great! Happy coding! :)

Comment: Why lower case the sentence five times when once will do?

Answer (score 0):

No need to make this difficult, even with the `for` loop constraint:

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'

sentence = input('Enter a string: ')

count = 0

for letter in sentence.lower():
    count += letter in VOWELS

print('There are {} vowels in the string: \'{}\''.format(count, sentence))
```

The heart of this is that booleans are also numbers that we can sum.  You can make `VOWELS` a `set('aeiou')` if you'll be processing lots of text and need added efficiency.  We can replace the `count` initialization and `for` loop with a generator expression:

```
count = sum(1 for c in sentence.lower() if c in VOWELS)
```

This is likely better than a list comprehension as it doesn't create a throwaway list and avoids processing a subset of the letters a second time.