# How can I make a function that prints the number of unique vowels in a string?

Tags: python

I am creating a program that prints the number of unique vowels in a string, whether upper or lower case. For example: "swEet” would print 1. What I have so far prints the number of vowels but not unique ones. What can I change or add to my code to do this? Thank you. I'm a beginner in Python and coding.

```
import sys

def count_vowels(sys_str):

    sys_str = sys.argv[1].upper()

    vowels = 'aeiou'

    count = len([c for c in sys_str.lower() if c in 
    vowels])

    return count

sys_str = sys.argv[1].upper()
count = count_vowels(sys_str)
print(count)
```

Source: DBrowne's answer at [Counting the number of vowels in a string using for loops in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397097/counting-the-number-of-vowels-in-a-string-using-for-loops-in-python) I got some of my code from this user in this question.

Comment: Simplest change is to turn your list comprehension `[c for c in ...]` into a set comprehension `{c for c in ...}`.

Comment: Why is 1 the result for Eat?

Comment: There are two unique vowels in "eat".

Comment: Why are you converting the input to uppercase and then calling `.lower()` in the loop? Just convert it to lowercase the first time.

Comment: `len(set("aeiou").intersection(input_string.lower()))`

Comment: Thank you @ddejohn ! That worked the best

Comment: @scwat don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted.

Comment: @ddejohn I would mark your answer as accepted but it is in a comment so I can't mark it, right?

Comment: I also posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

- First off `Eat` actually has 2 vowels "E" and "a".
- Second You won't need to use the sys module
- You can simplify your code to this if you're just trying to find the vowels in a string:

  ```
  def count_vowels(sys_str):
      vowels = 'aeiou'
      count = len([c for c in sys_str.lower() if c in vowels])
      return count
  ```
- As for finding unique vowels you can write something like this:

```
    def count_vowels(string):
        vowels = 'aeiou'
        hashmap = {}
        array = []

        for i, c in enumerate(string.lower()):
            if c not in hashmap:
                array.append(c)
                hashmap[c] = i
            else:
                array.pop(hashmap[c])
        return len(array)
```

Example:

```
count_vowels('Eeat')
Output: 1 #<- This is because there are 2 e's now so a is the only unique vowel
```

- Obviously, there's a lot more efficient time and space solution out there. This is just something off the top of my head. Hopes This helps!

Comment: 1. "hashmap" is called "dictionary" in python. 2. "eeat" should return 2, because OP wants "unique vowels", not "non-repeating vowels".

Answer (score 0):

Is there a requirement that you use `for` loops? The `set` type is much better suited to this type of problem -- no iteration necessary (at least in Python, there's obviously still iteration on the back end in C).

```py
VOWELS = set("aeiou")


def count_vowels(s: str) -> int:
    return len(VOWELS.intersection(s.lower()))
```

Examples:

```py
In [6]: count_vowels("Eat")
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: count_vowels("sweEt")
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: count_vowels("hello")
Out[8]: 2

In [9]: count_vowels("aeiou")
Out[9]: 5

In [10]: count_vowels("aeiou"*10)
Out[10]: 5

In [11]: count_vowels("")
Out[11]: 0

In [12]: count_vowels("syzygy")
Out[12]: 0
```